# Why are pounds sterling called "knicker"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I asked the price of an article the other day, and was told that it cost 120 *knicker*. This is a slang term for pounds sterling that always appears in the singular. I have failed find any reason why pounds should be referred to thus (it might also be *nicker* and I am imagining the silent *k*).

Is it some rhyming slang I am missing the back half of, or is there some other etymology?

Comment: I would note that the suffix "er" is commonly used in Scandinavian languages to pluralize a word.  Which would explain it's never being explicitly pluralized.

Comment: its sheffield slang not cockney lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED says it's origin is unknown, but suggests it could be originally horse racing slang and the first quotation from 1871 is in this context.

One of the other meanings of *nicker* is a neigh or neighing sound, originally Scottish, and imitative of horses or donkeys, and is from at least the 17th century. It also meant a laugh or a snicker.

Answer (score 10):

From this [reference](http://www.businessballs.com/moneyslanghistory.htm):

> **knicker**: distortion of 'nicker',
>   meaning £1. See entry under 'nicker'.
>   See also 'pair of knickers'.

And

> **nicker** - a pound (£1). Not pluralised
>   for a number of pounds, eg., 'It cost
>   me twenty nicker..' From the early
>   1900s, London slang, precise origin
>   unknown. Possibly connected to the use
>   of nickel in the minting of coins, and
>   to the American slang use of nickel to
>   mean a $5 dollar note, which at the
>   late 1800s was valued not far from a
>   pound. In the US a nickel is more
>   commonly a five cent coin. A nicker
>   bit is a one pound coin, and London
>   cockney rhyming slang uses the
>   expression 'nicker bits' to describe a
>   case of diarrhea.

And of course ;-)

> **pair of nickers/pair of knickers/pair o'nickers** - two pounds
>   (£2), an irresistible pun.

Comment: I don't buy the American connection.  First, pounds were notes, not coins, and even if, for some crazy reason, the British were taking their cues from the Americans, again highly doubtful, why would the word have changed from nickel to nicker.

Comment: @Sam: In England, *nicker* is pronounced *nicka*, which isn't so different from *nickel*. And both $5 dollar bills (***notes***), and 5¢ coins were called *nickels* in the U.S. (the first usage being slang). But Americans pluralized would have *nickels*.

Comment: In partial support of Sam, could I add that when I grew up in 50s and 60s England, 'half a crown' [2 shillings and sixpence, so one-eighth of a pound] was often referred to as 'half a dollar'  -  from the time, I was told, when there were about *four* dollars to a pound.

Comment: @DavidGarner I grew up with _half-dollar_ (2s6d or 12.5p) coins but I suspect that the use of _dollar_ for 5s is more Irish rather than English. I'm not quite sure when crown (5s) coins disappeared from circulation but I'm pretty sure that there was a lot more emigration to the US and return to the home country in Ireland than in the rest of the British Isles. Also I suspect that the Irish emigrants sent more money home than English as Ireland was more poverty-stricken, particularly following the Famine.

Comment: @BoldBen, fair point.  As for when the crown disappeared, they were legal tender throughout my childhood [1950s, 1960s] but I never once saw one used in a transaction    -  they appeared to be strictly commemorative.

Comment: @DavidGarner You must be about the same age as me, but I never saw a crown, I didn't even know they were technically legal tender. By the way did you ever spend a single farthing? I didn't even though little chew sweets were two for a ha'penny.

Comment: @BoldBen, born 1949 so I easily remember buying Blackjacks and Fruit Salads, which each cost a farthing [so you could have bought 960 for a pound].  Our smallest, and lowest valued, coin, decorated with our smallest bird, the wren.

Comment: @DavidGarner I'm the same age but I was brought up in rural Derbyshire, our local sweetie shop didn't sell them in ones!